# How to handle promise.all with express node.js ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, express, web-scraping, axios

I am webscraping a website using `axios` and `cheerio` and when I am trying to fetch a 20 ( more or less) links from the web, an `ECONNRESET` error is triggered. I am using the `promise.all` to handle it, but the mistake always appear. Is there any error on my code? How could I solve this?

```
let listEntrants    = await Promise.all(listCalls.map(async call =>{
                            let entrant    =   await getEntrantId(call.url);
                            return {attendee : call.attendee, entrant : entrant};
                    }));
```

The `listCalls` are the urls and the method `getEntrantId()` it return me the info I want.

Thanks.